# Bootstrap-like col-row-grid functionality on React Native?

Tags: layout, react-native, grid

It will be better if I demonstrate with images.

This is what I am trying to achieve. Assume landscape mode tablet size. Let's say I have X amount of elements in array. I want to map it across the row until it has 3 items in a row, then goes down. With bootstrap, I can do something like `col-md-4` three times.

[image: illustration]

Currently I am using `native-base`. It has an interesting [grid systems](https://blog.nativebase.io/dead-simple-layouts-with-react-native-2c611b0be8b1), but not exactly what I wanted.

This is what I have right now:

[image: current layout]

```
<Grid>
  <Row>
    { recipeStore.categories.map((category, index) => {
      return (
        <Col key={index} style={{height: 300}}>
          <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Body>
                <Text>{ category.name }</Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      )
    })}
  </Row>
</Grid>
```

How can I get the array iteration to fill out 3 columns then goes to the next row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on the parent contain and then use `flexBasis` on the children.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ABox = () => <View style={styles.box} />;

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ABox />
        <ABox />
        <ABox />
        <ABox />
        <ABox />
        <ABox />
        <ABox />
        <ABox />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  box: {
    flexBasis: 75,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    height: 40,
    margin: 10,
  }
});
```

Snack: https://snack.expo.io/HkUFUp7ub

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using the `FlatList` it is good in performance and easy to use. And it is recommended for making a list (see [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)). Additionally you don't need to add any extra package to your project.
You can easily use the `FlatList` as below:

```
 _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index; 

  _renderItem = ({item: category}) => (
    <Card>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <Text>{ category.name }</Text>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        numColumns={3}
        data={recipeStore.categories}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
```

Note: you should use the `numColumns` peroperty to define the number of items in each row.
You can see the documentation of `FlatList` in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html).

Comment: This does not answer the question, OP is asking how they can add a responsive layout to their app, this just describes how to make a list.